# How can Siu prove the lower semi-continuity of plurigenera by extension theorem?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am a novice in the field of complex geometry.  The following question seems to  be so  simple  that no one have explained  it in related papers.

In the famous paper---*Siu, Yum-Tong Invariance of plurigenera. Invent. Math. 134 (1998)* , **the main theorem is as follows.**

Let $\pi: X \rightarrow \Delta$ be a smooth projective family of compact complex manifolds parametrized by the open unit 1 -disk $\Delta$. Assume that the fibers $X_{t}=\pi^{-1}(t), t \in \Delta$, are of general type. Then for every positive integer $m$ the plurigenus $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbf{C}} \Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ is independent of $t \in \Delta$, where $K_{X_{t}}$ is the canonical line bundle of $X_{t}$.

**Siu reduced this problem to an extension problem**.  He wrote: "T**he Main Theorem is therefore equivalent** to the statement that for every $t \in \Delta$ and every positive integer $m$ every element of $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ can be extended to an element of $\Gamma\left(X, m K_{X}\right)$."

Accoding to my understanding, by the **Gruert upper-semicontinuity theorem**, that for every $t \in \Delta$ and every positive integer $m$ every element of $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ can be extended to an element of $\Gamma\left(X, m K_{X}\right)$  **is equivalent to the lower semi-continuity of  $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ near $t=0$.**

However I am unable to write it down step by step.

According to the definition of the  **lower semi-continuity**  and  $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)\in \mathbb{Z}$, **we need to  find a small positive number $\varepsilon$ such that  $\Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right) \leq  \Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ for any $t<\varepsilon$.**

So for a **fixed** small $t$, **we want to establish an injective map**
$$\Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right) \to  \Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right).$$

**Via the extension theorem, a natural map seens to be the following**.
$$v: s\mapsto S\mapsto S|_{X_t},$$
where $s\in \Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right)$, S its extension obtained by the extension theorem.

However, I **cannot prove the injectivity of the above map $v$**. In fact, for any different sections $s_1$  and $s_2$, we can find **some $\varepsilon$ (depends on $s_1$  and $s_2$**) such that $v(s_1)\neq v(s_2)$ for $t\leq \varepsilon$. But **the difficulty is that the choice of $\varepsilon$  depends on $s_1$  and $s_2$.**

So **we cannot compare the dimension** of $\Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right)$  with $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ **for a fixed** $t$.

***My question:*** How to prove the injectivity of the above map $v$. That is to say,  **how to compare the dimension** of $\Gamma\left(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}}\right)$  with $\Gamma\left(X_{t}, m K_{X_{t}}\right)$ **for a fixed** $t$.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siu's extension theorem tells us that the restriction map $\Gamma(X, m K_{X})\to\Gamma(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}})$ is surjective. This implies that the complex vector space $\Gamma(X_{0}, m K_{X_{0}})$ is isomorphic to $\pi_*\mathcal{O}(mK_X)/\mathfrak{m}_0\cdot\pi_*\mathcal{O}(mK_X)$, where $\mathfrak{m}_0$ is the defining ideal of $0\in\Delta$. Then (by, e.g., Section III.12 of Hartshorne's book) the sheaf $\pi_*\mathcal{O}(mK_X)$ is locally free in a neighborhood $U$ of $0$, and $\Gamma(X_t, m K_{X_t})\cong \pi_*\mathcal{O}(mK_X)/\mathfrak{m}_t\cdot\pi_*\mathcal{O}(mK_X)$ have the same dimension for all $t\in U$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanation from the point of view of AG.  
  By  III.12 of Hartshorne's book, you may mean Theorem 12.11  Cohomology and Base Change. Despite that we are talking in the analytic category, may as well assume that the related results are also right in  the analytic setting ( such results in analytic setting shouldn't be too hard to find).

Comment: Sorry, the whole is too long to right. I am confused by the local freeness of $\pi_{*} \mathcal{O}\left(m K_{X}\right)$ near $0$.  In   Hartshorne's book,  we now  need the condition  that  $\varphi^{i-1}(0)$ is also surjective 
for $i=0$.  Since $\varphi^{-1}(0)$ can not be welll defined,  it automatically holds.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, if you go through Hartshorne's argument for Theorem 12.11, the functor $T^0$ is automatically exact. You also could find a relevant analytic setting in Grauert and Remmert's book $\textit{Coherent Analytic Sheaves}$ (starting from page 207). A similar argument can be used to show the local freeness of $\pi_*\mathcal{O}(mK_X)$ near 0.